# Round (3 digits after the comma) a timestampdiff sql (Db2 for z/OZ)

Tags: db2

I have the following query:

```
Select AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(1, CHAR(TIMESTAMP(TIME_PROCESSED) - CHAR(TIMESTAMP(TIME_START))))) as Result
From Table A
```

The result is in micro seconds.

If I change the query to:

```
Select AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, CHAR(TIMESTAMP(TIME_PROCESSED) - CHAR(TIMESTAMP(TIME_START))))) as Result
From Table A
```

The result is in seconds but it shows me 0.

How can I modify the query that my result is in seconds with 3 digits after the comma? Example: 0,043

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting a result of 0 when using TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, ...) is because it calculates the difference between two timestamps in seconds, and if the difference is less than 1 second, it returns 0.

To get the result in seconds with 3 digits after the comma, you can use the FORMAT() function in MySQL to format the result to the desired precision. Here's the modified query:

```
SELECT FORMAT(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(1, CHAR(TIMESTAMP(TIME_PROCESSED) - CHAR(TIMESTAMP(TIME_START))))/1000000, 3) AS Result
FROM Table A;
```

In this query, I use AVG() to calculate the average time difference in microseconds, and then dividing it by 1000000 to convert it to seconds. The FORMAT() function is then used to format the result to 3 digits after the comma.

Comment: Hi and thank you but I have the following error:
No authorized function named FORMAT having compatible arguments was found. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884

Comment: This may be because the FORMAT function is not supported by your database system, or because you do not have the necessary permissions to use it.

You may want to consider using a different function or approach to achieve the desired formatting. One possible alternative is to use the DECIMAL function to format the result, like this: 
SELECT DECIMAL(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(2, CHAR(TIMESTAMP(TIME_PROCESSED) - TIMESTAMP(TIME_START))))/1000000, 10, 3) as Result
FROM Table A;

Answer (score 0):

When passing `1` to [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=functions-timestampdiff) we get time difference by microseconds, and if it is `2` we get seconds.

You will need to cast the Average result into `float`, then divide it by 100000, and then `CAST` the result to decimal to explicitly control the result precision and scale :

```
Select CAST( float(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(1, CHAR(TIMESTAMP(TIME_PROCESSED) - CHAR(TIMESTAMP(TIME_START))))))/ float(1000000) AS DECIMAL(5,3) ) as Result
From Table A
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZapFRf0T)

Comment: Thanks. I copied your answer and I get the following error:
Illegal symbol "(". Some symbols that might be legal are: ) CCSID ( For. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, Driver=4.31.10

Comment: Which version of db2 is this ?

Comment: I've added a demo can you have a look

Comment: DB2 for z/OS V12

Comment: Where can I find the demo?

Comment: I have added it to my answer https://dbfiddle.uk/ZapFRf0T